# Two tailed test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, data-mining

I have the following inputs:

- Avg score of the population
- Stddev of the populations score
- Sample size
- Avg score of the sample

Is is possible to compare the population and the sample by using two tailed test and only the given data?